# Sequqlize postgres - add amount only if the amount is greater than zero

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am looking for a sequelize query, such that I need the total amount of a table. But with a condition that add the amount only if it's greater than 0.

```
await model.post.findAll({
    where: {
        type: 'random',
    },
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'createdAt',
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('others.amount')), 'totalAmount'],
    ], include: [
        {
            model: model.other,
            attributes: [],
            required: false,
            duplicating: false,

        },
    ],
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    offset: (args.page - 1) * args.limit,
    limit: args.limit,
    raw: true,
    group: ['posts.id'],
});
```

In the above code, I just want to add the `others.amount` only if the amount is greater than zero.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = await db.Post.findAll({
    where: {
        type: 'random',
    },
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'createdAt',
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('other.amount')), 'totalAmount'],
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Other,
            attributes: [],
            required: false,
            duplicating: false,
            as: 'other',
            where: {
                amount: { [Op.gte]: 0 } // grater than 0
            }
        },
    ],
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    raw: true,
    group: ['Post.id'],
});
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)))
```

Added `where : ...` inside `include`

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/stack-66265977/test/db.js